# get value from data grid onselection

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm, binding, datagrid

i am new to wpf mvvm.for getting value from data grid on selection,i have created a property that is of object datatype.when am clicking on data grid row i get set of values containing first name,last-name,city,state,pin,mobileno,mail id,employee id etc.i need to retrieve employee id from that for updation purpose..but i don't know how to retrieve those values from that property declared in object datatype..please help me....\

this is my view model

```
public object selectedEmployee;
public object SelectedEmployee
{
    get
    {
        return selectedEmployee;
    }
    set
    {
        selectedEmployee = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedEmployee");
    }
}
```

this is my xaml code

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" x:Name="grdEmployee" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeDatatable, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  IsReadOnly="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="59,0,86,12" Width="492" CanUserAddRows="False"  
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Emp_id}" Header="Employee ID"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirstName}" Header="FirstName"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastName}" Header="LastName"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Age}" Header="Age"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ZipCode}" Header="ZipCode"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PhoneNumber}" Header="PhoneNumber"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MobileNumber}" Header="MobileNumber"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Name="btnEdit" Content="Edit"></Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude, you *must* have put a custom object of some type (that has those properties) into your `object` variable. All you have to do is to cast the `object` back to its original type and then you will be able to access the properties again. Because I don't know what type it is, for this example, I am going to imagine that you have a class named `Employee` that has these properties. This is how you cast an object:

```
Employee employee = (Employee)yourRowObject;
// Now you can access the properties. For example...
string fullName = string.Concat(employee.Firstname, " ", employee.LastName);
int employeeId = employee.Id;
```

Comment: i got another way to get access to the column values of datagrid..anyway thank you for your help...